# React Native Navigation problem when using nested navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have recently came across with a bug in which I have 2 nested navigator and when I switch from the first screen of the nested navigator to second screen of the navigator, and I logged out, I will arrive at login screen but with multiple instance of render (the screen will blink twice). Moreover, when I logged in again, it will navigate me to the last screen I am when I logged out instead of my initial route. However, if I did not render to second screen, the problem will not appear. How can I solve this?

```
const HomeStack = ({navigation}) => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={20} />
        ),
      }}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      name="UpdateExpense"
      component={UpdateExpense}
      options={{
        title: 'Edit Expense',

        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          shadowColor: '#fff',
          elevation: 0,
        },
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="AddExpense"
      component={AddExpense}
      options={{
        title: 'Add Expense',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          shadowColor: '#fff',
          elevation: 0,
        },
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const BudgetStack = ({navigation}) => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Budget">
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Budget"
      component={BudgetScreen}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarLabel: 'Budget',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Ionicons name="chart" color={color} size={20} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="AddBudget" component={AddBudget} />
    <Stack.Screen name="EditBudget" component={EditBudget} options={{}} />

    <Stack.Screen
      name="ChartScreen"
      component={ChartScreen}
      options={{headerTitle: 'Chart'}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
const AppStack = () => {
  const getTabBarVisibility = route => {
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? '';

    if (routeName == 'AddExpense') {
      return 'none';
    } else if (routeName == 'UpdateExpense') {
      return 'none';
    } else if (routeName == 'ChartScreen') {
      return 'none';
    } else if (routeName == 'AddBudget') {
      return 'none';
    } else if (routeName == 'EditBudget') {
      return 'none';
    } else return 'flex';
  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#2e64e5',
        initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeStack"
        component={HomeStack}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarVisible: route.state && route.state.index === 0,
          tabBarStyle: {display: getTabBarVisibility(route)},
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={20} />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="BudgetStack"
        component={BudgetStack}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Budget',
          tabBarStyle: {display: getTabBarVisibility(route)},
          tabBarVisible: route.state && route.state.index === 0,
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="attach-money" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: {display: getTabBarVisibility(route)},
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Ionicons name="person-outline" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {getAuth, onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthProvider';

import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';

const Routes = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

  const onAuthStateChange = user => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, onAuthStateChange);
    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

```
 <SuperButton
        style={{width: 390}}
        text="Logout"
        onPress={() => logout()}
      />
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, just not specifically with authentication, but more in general. I work with a FlatList on my initial route which makes it even more visible, because it's state will be reset with every rerender. So, are there any updates on this?